# IF with duration (hh:mm:ss)

Tags: datetime, google-sheets

I have a column of durations that I received in text format looking like `00:01:20s`. I removed the `s` from the end and formatted it as duration in Google Sheets, so the text `00:01:20` became duration `00:01:20`.

What I'd like to do is take each entry that is `0:00:00` and change it to `0:00:01`. Here's my formula (where column B contains the duration):

```
=if(B2=00:00:00,00:00:01,B2)
```

When I run it, I get *Formula parse error.*

I double-checked to make sure that column B was usable in calculations by adding two cells, and the result was correct. The column in which I put the formula is also formatted as duration. I've been Googling, and somehow haven't found another case of this error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I avoid Duration format (at least for the time being!) but please try:

```
=if(VALUE(B2)=0,time(0,0,1),B2)
```

Comment: Oops -- I thought that fixed it, but it didn't.

If the duration was already 00:00:01, it remained so, but if it was originally 00:00:00, it was changed to 12:00:01 AM.

Comment: Is there a way to move this to the Web Applications section, or should I just delete this and post again there?

Comment: Okay, fiddled around and got this to work:

=if(value(B2)=0,0.00001,B2)  I'll ask the mod to move it -- thanks for the formula tip and the mod tip :)